# Nested Waterfall's function not called in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have following code in NodeJS:

```
Vasync.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        Model.Test.findOne({
            id: id,
        }).exec(callback);
    },
    function (test, callback) { // determine go to which function
        method(test, callback);
    },
], function (error, result) {
    res.send(response);
});

function method(test, parentCallback) {
    ...
    Vasync.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            log.info("test 1");
            Model.Item.findOne({
                test: test
            }).exec(callback);
        },
        function (item, callback) {
            log.info("test 2");
            callback(null, "");
        }
    ], function (error, result) {
        log.info("test 3");
        parentCallback(error, result);
    });
}
```

It prints `test 1`, but never reaches `test 2` and directly goes to `test 3`. What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: are you sure that Model.Item.findOne({test: test}).exec(callback); query gets executed successfully with out any error.

Comment: Yup that's the cause! I find that when I have `.select()`, there is unwanted space..

Comment: from test 1 function remove callback from exec and put outside, bcz ur test 1 is not giving callback that's the reason its not gng to text 2

Comment: I have found out it was because the query throws error of unwanted space inside my `select`.

Comment: haha, your code is fine, just that you query is throwing an error, that's the reason.

Comment: you can close the question is solved, along with the solution you came with.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the error field to know your error